# Foreach loop on several instances of same class

Tags: c#, foreach

I am trying to make an airline reservation system, as this was my coworkers examination project, and so I figured if I do this I could work towards the same level as him. I am a PHP (yes, OO) programmer moving on to C#.

I have created several versions of a class, as such:

```
    Vluchten flight1 = new Vluchten("1337", "Scandinavian Airlines", "Oslo Intl", 180, 162);
    Vluchten flight2 = new Vluchten("101", "KLM", "Derpistan", 20, 17);
    Vluchten flight3 = new Vluchten("112", "Ryan Air", "Doetinchem Rock City", 10, 7);
```

Now I was wondering, I've made these all right, but is there a way I can loop through this so I can then put them in a datagridview table?

Comment: Why not use a collection of `Vluchten`? Perhaps `List<Vluchten>`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to put them into a `List<Vluchten>`, and then you can easily use a `foreach` loop

```
List<Vluchten> flights = new List<Vluchten>() { flight1, flight2, flight3 };

foreach(Vluchten flight in flights)
{
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize them into an array or list, instead of individual objects:

```
var flights = new[]
{
     new Vluchten("1337", "Scandinavian Airlines", "Oslo Intl", 180, 162),
     new Vluchten("101", "KLM", "Derpistan", 20, 17),
     new Vluchten("112", "Ryan Air", "Doetinchem Rock City", 10, 7)
};

foreach (var flight in flights)
{

}
```

Comment: Please don't use `var` when explaning `List` and `Collection` to someone new to the language. This will only hide one of the strengths of a typed language.

Comment: I believe using `var` is a matter of personal preference and shouldn't add or detract from any solution.  OP is welcome to ask about it if needed.

Comment: I would encourage the use of `var` especially when educating new comers to C#.

Answer (score 1):

A quicker way to make them a list:

```
var flights = new List<Vluchten>
{
    new Vluchten("1337", "Scandinavian Airlines", "Oslo Intl", 180, 162),
    new Vluchten("101", "KLM", "Derpistan", 20, 17),
    new Vluchten("112", "Ryan Air", "Doetinchem Rock City", 10, 7)
};
```

`var` is a simple way to create a new variable of a unknown type.

`List<Vluchten>` is telling C# we want a list of the type `Vluchten`

`{}` inside these curly braces we list a bunch of instantiated objects. This is short hand for `flights.Add()`

Then you can use this *extension method* to iterate over them:

```
flights.ForEach(f => ..);
```

Where `f` is the `Vluchten`. The `..` you can put `{}` to denote a method body which manipulates each object or you can put a one line `ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine(f.Id))`

`ForEach` is just short for `foreach (var item in flights) {}`

*LINQ* can be used on the collection to query it. Such functions include `Where`, `Any`, `Select`

Simples.

I advise that you search on the terms that are *italic* to get a good understanding of the C# language as a whole

Comment: You think OP is going to understand the incomplete lambda expression you posted here when they aren't aware of loops and lists? I think this could be a good answer but you need to elaborate on the last bit.

Comment: BTW, it is not linq. it's just a method of `List<T>`

Comment: I think they would already be aware of these basic language constructs (arrays, for loops). He came from PHP, so should understand a lot of constructs. I've opened up the floor for him to research these different things to broaden his knowledge of the C# language. So rather then just show him something simple, give him the opportunity to get stuck into the language

Comment: ForEach method. It's part of `System.Collections.Generic`